# SignalR - Leave All Groups

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Using a SignalR hub clients can be added or removed from a group. A client can belong to multiple groups. Is it possible to remove a client from every group it currently belongs to? I guess what I'm looking for is something like `Clients[*allgroups*].leave(Context.ConnectionId)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they have yet to implement this, but it is considered a candidate for v3. A feature request with the following code exists at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/66

```
public static class SignalRConnectionToGroupsMap
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>  Map = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public static bool TryAddGroup(string connectionId, string groupName)
    {
        List<string> groups;

        if (!Map.TryGetValue(connectionId, out groups))
        {
            return Map.TryAdd(connectionId, new List<string>() {groupName});
        }

        if (!groups.Contains(groupName))
        {
            groups.Add(groupName);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // since for this use case we will only want to get the List of group names
    // when we're removing the mapping - we might as well remove the mapping while
    // we're grabbing the List
    public static bool TryRemoveConnection(string connectionId, out List<string> result)
    {
        return Map.TryRemove(connectionId, out result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of v0.5.2, there is no way to leave all groups because the server doesn't keep track of the groups a client belongs to. You need to do this yourself and remove the client from each group one-by-one.

There's a request for something similar in the backlog however, so maybe this will be implemented in a future release: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/66

Comment: Then how does `Client["GroupName"].WhateverMethod()` know to only send the message to clients in "GroupName"?

Comment: A SignalR connection (the channel from server to client) is listening for specific messages or "signals", like connection id or group name, which are roundtripped via querystring. The message bus that serves as the backplane is (in a simplified form) just a dictionary that uses this information as the key and when you invoke a client-side method it just puts "WhateverMethod" as the value into the dictionary. All connections listening for this key are then given the data asynchronously. Leaving all groups would need a special command telling the clients to stop listening, which isn't there yet.