# Remove connection from all groups in SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

How can I remove a specific connection from all groups in SignalR? - In my application the connection of a specific user can be associated with several groups. I don't want to use a database to track the association of the connection to groups.

[SignalIR docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#grouppersistence)

Comment: You cannot, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442591/signalr-leave-all-groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be iterate over all the groups and remove the connection id from each of them. There isn't an inbuilt method in SignalR to do this.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My problem is that I can have thousands of groups even more. Each group with its own unique name. How can I iterate the groups (I am also using Redis as the back-end) - any code sample?