# How to remove all clients from a SignalR group?

Tags: c#, signalr

So in SignalR, you can add clients to a group using

```
Groups.Add(connectionId, roomName)
```

And you can remove a client from a group using

```
Groups.Remove(connectionId, roomName);
```

But how can I just empty a group - in other words, just removing all the clients from that group?

**UPDATE:** This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442591/signalr-leave-all-groups) because I am asking how to remove **ALL clients** from **ONE group**. I'm not asking to remove oneclient from all groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SignalR - Leave All Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442591/signalr-leave-all-groups)

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes I'm not asking to remove a user from all its group, but to remove all users from one group.

Comment: Maybe this could help,but it is old: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/66

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Aspram!

Answer (score 4):

SignalR does not expose any method to do that. It also does not expose a list of active connections. So to achieve what you want, you'd have to store all connection IDs by implementing `OnConnectedAsync` and then remove them from a group in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find any API function for this too but Groups is of Dictionary type (as far as I remember) so you can use Clear() function. If not look what interface|type Groups implements and use its function like Clear()

Comment: ```Groups``` is of type ```IGroupManager``` and it only offers ```Add``` and ```Remove``` AFAIK.

Comment: @Mason then i suppose the only way is to delete all records one by one :(. Because Aspram shared doc proves that since 2011 this problem is not solved lol